# How best create a visual model of EF Code First after VS2013 Update 2?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I know the EF Power Tools offers this but am loath to install them after installing VS2013 Update 2 since some of the Power Tool features are now part of Update 2. I already spent a good part of yesterday reinstalling VS2013 w/ integrated Update 2 after installing/uninstalling EF 6.1.0 Tools broke using the ADO.NET project templates. Is there anything built into Update 2 that allows this?

Comment: Honestly, the quickest way is usually by generating a database diagram via SQL Server Management Studio. Assuming the database has been generated, and your question is meant purely as a visual represenation of the model.

Comment: Yes that seems the best bet at this point. Oddly they removed this from Visual Studio so you have to use SSMS. If you can post as such, I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Answer posted :) Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @Flater I see now you added it as an answer so will mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the quickest way is usually by generating a database diagram via SQL Server Management Studio. Assuming the database has been generated, and your question is meant purely as a visual representation of the model.